# Remplace NAN with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have this dataframe, I want to replace the NaN of the region column according to the area of membership ...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'area':['North America','Belgique','France','Angleterre','Asie','N Zelande','Italie'],
        'region':['NA','Nan','Europe','Autres','Nan','Nan','Nan']})`


area           | region |
------------------------
North America  | NA     |
Belgique       | Nan    |
France         | Europe |
Angleterre     | Autres |
Asie           | Nan    |
N Zelande      | Nan    |
Italie         | Nan    |
```

`
i want this output

```
area           | region |
------------------------
North America  | NA     |
Belgique       | Europe |
France         | Europe |
Angleterre     | Europe |
Asie           | Autres |
N Zelande      | Autres |
Italie         | Europe |
```

Comment: Have you try `.fillna()`?

Comment: yes, i try but i did not succeed

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
dict_of_areas={'NA':'North america','Belgique':'Europe'}
df.loc[df['region'].isnull(),'region']=df.loc[df['region'].isnull(),'area'].replace(dict_of_areas)
```

You can use `dict_of_areas` to map regions into areas.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but i want to remplace the NaN (no string, sorry) by the good region. For example for the NaN with area=Belgique i want to put the region according to Belgique, like Europe, for the NaN with area = Asie -> put Autres ... etc

Comment: sorry but no because you remplace the NaN of the region by the value of area without condition. In this case for belgique i want to put Europe not Belgique, you see what i mean ?

Comment: @DAVID Yes. Your question was really unclear, I updated my answer.

Comment: @DAVID Sure, if my answer solved your issue please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This you can try.It is filtering the *region* values where the value is either *Nan* or *NA* and assigning the *area* value to that particular *region*

```
    df['region'][df['region'].isin(["Nan","NA"])]=df['area']
```

For me it's giving output as below.

| area | region |
| --- | --- |
| North America | North America |
| Belgique | Belgique |
| France | Europe |
| Angleterre | Autres |
| Asie | Asie |
| N Zelande | N Zelande |
| Italie | Italie |

Is this the same output you are expecting?

Comment: No, i want to put the Europe(for region) for Belgique for example, Europe for Italie, Autre for Asie etc ...